# Why does tempfile seem to delete itself within a with statement?

Tags: python, filesystems, browser, temporary-files

This program is a browser that is designed to circumvent proxy settings. As you can see when the data is processed it is put into a file and opened in the default browser. However when I open it in chrome (I don't know if that is significant), it says:

`This web page has not been found`

`No web page was found for the web address:` `file:///C:/Users/Thornton/appdata/local/temp/tmpreb9zp.html`

`Error code: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Here is the code:

```
import urllib.request
import webbrowser
import tempfile
from tkinter import *


class Browser:

    def __init__(self, master):
        global e1

        self.proxy_handler = urllib.request.ProxyHandler(proxies=None)
        self.opener = urllib.request.build_opener(self.proxy_handler)

        Label(master, text='Full Path').grid(row=0)
        e1 = Entry(master)
        e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        Button(master, text='Go', command=self.browse).grid(row=0, column=2)
        root.bind('<Return>', self.browse)

    @staticmethod
    def parsed(data):
        initial = str(data)[2:-1]
        lines = initial.split('\\n')
        return lines

    def navigate(self, query):
        response = self.opener.open(query)
        html = self.parsed(response.read())
        return html

    def browse(self):
        raw_data = self.navigate(e1.get())
        clean_data = self.parsed(raw_data)

        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.html') as cache:
            cache.writelines(line.encode('UTF-8') for line in clean_data)
            webbrowser.open_new_tab(cache.name)

root = Tk()
root.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)
app = Browser(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because tempfiles are [deleted when closed](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile), and the `with` statement does exactly that, and the webbrowser module does not wait for completion. From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/webbrowser.html):

> For non-Unix platforms, or when a remote browser is available on Unix,
>   the controlling process will not wait for the user to finish with the
>   browser

Comment: NamedTemporaryFile takes a keyword argument `delete=False`. Maybe use that? It's all in the documentation.